# How do I use a Cordova plugin in ionic capacitor with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I can't figure out how to use this capacitor plugin in my vue.js component. Or any ionic native or cordova plugins..
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts

I can get capacitor api's to work just fine.
https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/device

Any knowledge appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am looking to do the same thing and can't find any tutorials specifically around this workflow.

Comment: I didn't yet. It wasn't crucial for me so I'm holding off for now.

Comment: btw the contact plugin actually maintained by cordova and now its deprecated.

hopefully ionic capasitor can add this contact as built in plugin

Comment: As of some time Capacitor has its own plugin for accessing contacts: https://github.com/capacitor-community/contacts

Answer (score 4):

Here's what ended up working for me:

I viewed the plugins on Ionic's site: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase (in my case) and then for the install I ran `npm install cordova-plugin-inapppurchase` and then ran `npm install @ionic-native/in-app-purchase`. Then in my Vue JS file I imported the plugin using `import { InAppPurchase } from '@ionic-native/in-app-purchase/ngx';`

The next part is what tripped me up. On the next line I had to create a new variable to access the referenced plugin. So the next line of code is `const iap = new InAppPurchase();`

Then you can access the `iap` variable and use all the documented methods from within your Vue app.

Keep in mind that any testing of Cordova plugins will need to happen on your device.

Hope this helps anyone who was struggling like me!

Comment: It doesn't work. How about another cordova plugin like "cordova-plugin-qrscanner-allanpoppe2"

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation here
https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/using-cordova-plugins
you should be able to do

```
npm i cordova-plugin-contacts
npm i @ionic-native/contacts
npx cap sync
```

Just remember

> Important: Configuration
>   Capacitor does not support Cordova install variables, auto configuration, or hooks, due to our philosophy of letting you control your native project source code (meaning things like hooks are unnecessary). If your plugin requires variables or settings to be set, you'll need to apply those configuration settings manually by mapping between the plugin's plugin.xml and required settings on iOS and Android.
>
> Consult the iOS and Android configuration guides for info on how to configure each platform.
>
> Compatibility Issues
>   Some Cordova plugins don't work with Capacitor or Capacitor provides a conflicting alternative. See here for details and a known incompatibility list.

Comment: How do you import the Ionic Native plugin into a Vue + Capacitor project? With Angular you normally include it as a provider and then create instance in the constructor, but it's unclear how to use Ionic Native plugins in Vue + Capacitor project. 

When I `import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';`, I get  `Can't resolve '@angular/core' in '/node_modules/@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx'`.

But when I try `import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';`, I get `cordova_not_available`.

Answer (score 0):

The Capacitor Community has its own contacts plugin: https://github.com/capacitor-community/contacts

It's preferred to use that repository (currently maintained by me) instead of the cordova one. Its codebase is cleaner, more up-to-date and better maintained. Moreover, it's specifically targeting Capacitor. Therefore the compatibility will be guaranteed.